# "IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic" vs "IIS: Dynamic Content Compression"?

Tags: iis, web-platform-installer

What's the difference between the first 2 entries in this list and the highlighted entries?

[image: One]

Comment: Also, bonus question, what is "IIS Compression Module 1.0"?

Comment: If you use Control Panel or Server Manager to enable IIS components, you won't be confused by such ambiguous items. They are created as Web Platform Installer add-ons, but personally I never use them at all.

Comment: @LexLi Cool... I was actually on my way to add the compression modules the way you suggested when I stumbled upon this and was confused by the options. I ended up just adding them all though and looks like it accomplished what I wanted as far as I can tell.